# Get onCorruption callback in RoomDatabase without breaking existing implementation

Tags: android, android-room

I need to know database corruption so that i can re-initialize a single instance object of 'RoomDatabase'.

I would like to get `onCorruption`, What would be configuration to get such callback.

Comment: Is there any update on this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69722729/what-happens-when-room-android-db-gets-corrupted/69729602#69729602